# Selenium webdriver select text of a subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have one class nested inside another class:

```
<div>
    <div class="label">
        <div class="title">My Title 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        <div class="title">My Title 2</div>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

How do I get a list of `My Title 1, My Title 2`?  I have tried this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='label']/div[@class='title]")
```

But got this error `The string '//div[@class='label']/div[@class='title]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

I have also tried:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".label .title")
```

But also got nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get a list of all title texts

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='label']/div[@class='title']/text()")
print(titles)
```

Comment: I want the `title` classes inside the `label` classes only! There may be `title` classes somewhere else, which I don't want

Comment: Ok. i see you have missed a single quote in your xpath expression.  see my updated answer.

Comment: Could you tested with an example? because this does not work in my case. It still returns zero element

Comment: Yes. I have tested this xpath using an online tool. This xpath return list of strings ( not web elements) . Are you getting any errors? I don’t have your complete html source. So can’t test this 100%. You may to need to some additional wait time before  running this xpath.